# If $\sigma(\alpha)$ takes finitely many values when $ \sigma$ runs over automorphism (as field) of $ \Bbb{C}$, why $ \alpha$ is algebraic number?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, automorphism-group

Let $ \alpha$ be complex number.
If $\sigma(\alpha)$ takes finitely many values when $ \sigma$ runs over automorphism (as field) of $ \Bbb{C}$, why $ \alpha$ is algebraic number ?

To prove this, firstly I want to prove $\Bbb{Q}( \alpha)/\Bbb{Q}$ is finite extension.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have basic knowledge about transcendental bases, e.g. that every bijection between two transcendental bases of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ extends to an automorphism?

Comment: I studied some property of transcendental bases with Milne's field theory, but I didn't know that statement, What does bases extends to an automorphism and what have to do with this question ?

Comment: Let $\sigma_1(\alpha), \ldots, \sigma_m(\alpha)$ be the finitely many distinct values and consider the polynomial $f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^m (x-\sigma_i(\alpha))$. Can you show that $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and that $\alpha$ is a root of $f$?

Comment: $ \alpha$ is a root of $f$ is obvious because for some $i$, $ \sigma_i=α$.

Comment: I may should think of some galois group action over $ \Bbb{Q}$, but I'm having trouble. Could you tell me why $f$'s coefficient is in $ \Bbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: From staring really hard at the definition of $f$ in Viktor's comment you can conclude that every coefficient is fixed by every automorphism (please try this yourself!). Now being fixed by automorphisms is a well known property of elements of $\mathbb{Q}$. The question that remains is if elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ are the *only* complex numbers that are fixed by all field automorphisms. I believe the answer is yes, but it needs some arguing.

Comment: We may need a set theorist here also. I may be wrong, but I think the existence of automorphisms of $\Bbb{C}$ other than the two obvious ones requires the Axiom of Choice.